# Not able to copy data manually from the ng2-tooltip-directive tooltip

Tags: angular, tooltip, ng2-tooltip-directive

I have a **ng2-tooltip-directive** tooltip with html content in it. When hover over a text this tooltip appears. But when I try to move the cursor into the tooltip content(to copy the tooltip data) it disappears. Requirement is to copy the tooltip content manually. Please help.

```
<div style="display: inline-block">
                <span style="font-size: small;">ToolTip: </span>&nbsp;
                <span [ngClass]="getContractcodeClass()" 
                        [tooltip]="ToolTipContent" 
                        content-type="template"
                        trigger = "hover"
                        placement="bottom"
                        theme="light"
                        [display]="showContractCodeDataOnHovering"
                        max-width="500"
                        offset="0"
                        pointerEvents="auto"
                        hide-delay="200">{{ToolTipData}}
                </span>
            </div>


 <ng-template #ToolTipContent>
    <html>
        <br/>
        <body style="padding-left: 15px;">
        <strong>{{contractCodeKeys?.ContractCodeDetails}}</strong>
        <div><p style="width: 95%; display: table;"></p></div>
        <div class="row">
            <p style="width: 95%;  margin-right: 10px;display: table;">
               <span style="display: table-cell; border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.404);"></span>
            </p>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
            <span class="columnName">{{id}}</span>
            <span class="columnValue">{{idValue}}</span>
        </div><br/>
        <div class="row">
            <span class="columnName">{{name}}</span>
            <span class="columnValue">{{nameValue}}</span>
        </div><br/>        
        </body>
        </html>
</ng-template>
```

css below

```
.value-contractcode{
    font-weight: 700 !important;
  } 
  .value-contractcodeNumber{
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    color:#006bbd
  }
  .text-contractcode{
    font-size: small;
    padding-left:50px
  }  
  .columnName {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    color: grey
  }
  .columnValue {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 60%;
    font-weight:bold;
  }

  .row{
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

Comment: we need code to help you man! :)

Comment: @Dario updated with code

Comment: how you compute you `showContractCodeDataOnHovering` ? maybe the mistake is here

Comment: display property takes by default true value right. so even after removing the display property It behaves the same old way. while moving to the tooltip content it hides

Comment: How can I retain the tooltip data to be visible when move the cursor over there?

Comment: hav you treid to leave  hide-delay="200" ?

Comment: hey @PraveenK did  you find a solution to this? I also want to keep the tooltip open when its hovered

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can not copy the text because of using hover effect instead of click.
If you investigate demo of click and hover -  http://ivylab.space/tooltip/demo,  you will see that you can copy the text using click only.